# Unable to get MiniEdit working using SSH

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, powershell, putty

I am having difficulty getting MiniEdit to work using SSH. Upon importing the appliance into VirtualBox I logged in and ran the command

```
sudo apt install xinit
```

I then changed the network adaptor to host only from NAT so I could log in with SSH but when I ran the command

```
 sudo ~/mininet/examples/miniedit.py
```

I got the error:

```
 _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

so I tried startx but it just told me the user I was running under wasn't authorised and I tried it in the VM itself and it worked. My question is how do I get it working in PuTTY. I've even tried running it with the Windows Powershell SSH client

Is my only option using the VM itself?

Comment: In VirtualBox VM settings, use one network interface as NAT for Internet and another one as Host-Only interface for ssh from host to guest.

Comment: The first time I tried to do startx from Powershell, I got a timeout and then now it gives me the message invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the option '-X' so you can put in bash:
ssh -X user@ip